# After Migration no route page content display on every product page

Tags: magento2, 404-page, magento2-migration-tool

I have done migration from magento 1.9.3.1 to 2.1.3 by migration tool 2.1.3. Every things is working except one thing.

Every product page called first no-route page after product details is displayed. both page (404page + product detail )content display together , juts like this image[image].

There is in console i have seen first request is pass with product url like : "Network Error: 404 Not Found - http://localhost/georeef/lps-coral/fire-ice.html" , after that all request passed.[image]

Anyone have the idea why happen this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue but still not able to find the proper solution. If i save the product manually from the admin side, it works very well for that product. But as i am a technical guy, this is not a proper solution. Please help me in this.

Comment: You can save all products from admin at once, I have not found any other solution for that

Answer (score 0):

Backup your database and remove data from table

> catalog_url_rewrite_product_category

and then run reindex command

> php bin/magento indexer:reindex
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

Comment: I have truncate table but its not regenerate  by reindex process and url structure has been changed like this http://localhost/georeef_new/catalog/product/view/id/61/s/bubba/category/4/ , its not working @parasarora1303

Comment: what data migration tool did you used?

Comment: Migration CLI tool version 2.1.3